# What PLC language is this?

Tags: plc

Has any one seen a PLC'ish programming language such as this below.  I am trying to find some reference as to how to read it correctly.  It could be something of a bespoke construction.

```
1   Put Signal Value    V_Flg18
2   NOT
3   Duplicate Stack
4   Duplicate Stack
5   If True, Clear Signal   wAcc10
6   If True, Clear Timer        10
7   If True, Exit
8   Put Signal Value    wAcc10
9   Read Timer      11
10  Put Literal Value       1
11  >
12  Read Timer      11
13  Put Literal Value       40
14  <
15  AND
16  Mask VHM DOut, Hx       4000
17  Put Literal Value       3
18  >=
19  If True, Exit
20  Put Signal Value    V_Flg23
21  Detect Pos Transition       20
22  Put Signal Value    V_Flg32
23  NOT
24  AND
25  Duplicate Stack
26  Duplicate Stack
27  Duplicate Stack
28  If True, Start Timer        11
29  If True, Set Signal V_Flg32 1
30  If True, Set Signal I_Flg10     1
31  NOT
32  If True, Clear Signal   I_Flg10
```

Comment: Looks like a curiously verbose instruction list, I'm trying to find it out...

Comment: Hi, did you make any progress? It is clear that the `If True` instructions cause a stack pop, that's why they are preceded by an equal number of `Duplicate Stack`. What I'm not sure is if the `AND` instruction involves only the first two elements or all the elements in the stack (in the first case, some values seem to be left behind).

Comment: I came to similar deductions about the 'stack' approach.  However its hard to be certain about the exact interpretation of the logic without some kind of reference.  I have not seen anything even similar before.

Comment: It definitely seems a bespoke construction. Right now I'm only unsure about the "scope" of the `END` operation and perhaps about the `Mask` instruction, though `4000` should really be an hexadecimal (`Hx`) mask to deal with bit 14. All the rest is quite clear, thanks to the verbosity of the instructions, except the meaning of the symbolic names, of course (though the names containing `Flg` likely refer to boolean flags), but that isn't a big problem if you know the context (which I've really got no idea about :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Assembly language with address labels defined.